# Integrate NopCommerce with Angular 8 UI

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular8, nopcommerce

I am going to handle a project which is very similar to an eCommerce website.
I am thinking of leveraging NopCommerce framework for the same.
I would like to build UI with Angular 8.
I want to know can I integrate Angular 8 code with NopCommerce which runs on asp.net core 3.1.
If someone has done a similar work, can you please share any examples?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: When working with angular, you typically want to communicate with the server using an api that returns data only (json). With NopCommerce you can create such apis or use existing plugings.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your angular app to NopCommerce through a REST API. It seems like you can achieve this by means of a plugin for Nop. There are paid one, but this one is free and has some decent reviews: https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/api-plugin